# Is it possible to exclude certain projects in a solution from hot reload in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, .net-6.0, visual-studio-debugging

Currently our hot reload takes a looong time (over 20 seconds). This is because its tracking changes over 50+ class libraries (I think), while we really only change 1 project.

Is it possible to somehow exclude these projects from hot reload to make it perform faster? On new projects it's so unbelievably fast.

The only solution I've found is to disable hot reload in launchSettings.json which would turn the feature off.

Comment: Can you trick VS into thinking the package is not your code, maybe `<ProjectReference ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" ... /><Reference ... [explicit path to dll] ... />` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is NO.**

Everything about hot reload feature of VS tool is here:

[Hot Reload in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload?view=vs-2022)

No such sub feature you want.